# Group by concat in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m using multiple joins for a specific logic , but encountered a problem . Some of the records has 1-2 relation in one of the tables which mess up my output. I want to concat all these string so it will appear it one record, but I don’t know how to do it in sql server . In oracle and MySQL it’s easy but I tried playing with online examples and failed miserably.

My query:

```
SELECT c.customerName,c.Guid,p.campaignTitle ,
              (SELECT k.campaignTitle FROM [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].campaigns l JOIN [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].campaignstitle k on k.campaignname = l.campaignname where l.campaignid = t.referrerurl) as  Referrertitle,
              t.activitydate,t.type
  FROM  [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].campaignknowncustomers c
  join  [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].[CampaignCustomerMatch] t ON(c.guid = t.visitorexternalid)
  join  [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].campaigns s ON(t.url = s.campaignid)
  join  [DEV_TEST2].[dbo].campaignstitle p on(s.campaignname = p.campaignname)
  order by customername,activitydate
```

My problem is with campaigntitle column and referrertitle correlated  query. Both come from the same table. I need to concat it and show only 1 row per ‘customername, guid, activitydate’

Comment: It is not easy in SQL Server, unless you are using a very recent version that supports `string_agg()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not available for me :/

Comment: There are many duplicate questions that show how to do that. All of them use one or another technique found in [Aaron Bertrand's articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). A SQLCLR aggregate is the fastest option. Using `FOR XML` is a close second. Anything else takes far longer.

Comment: @Yossi which version are you targeting? SQL Server 2017 added `STRING_AGG`. SQL Server 2016 added JSON support. Formatting the results of the subquery as JSON and stripping the suffix, prefix characters could be enough if you don't mind quoted strings

Comment: If it is somehow ensured that there can at most be 2 related records, you could do something with PIVOT.

Comment: @panagiotiskanavos I’m using sql server 2016. String quotes are a bit of a problem , though I can simply run replace after words no?

Comment: @wolfgangkais for now I see two, but there is no assurance there won’t be more ..

Comment: Never mind there’s even a record with 6 matches

Comment: @Yossi what if the *data* contains quotes? Try the XML technique first.